# How to execute an import module in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I imported a module (`.bas`) into my excel project.

However, when I click on the button `Run`, Excel ask me the macro name and even if I put the name of my macro, this is not working because the `Execute` button is disabled.

Someone can help me to fix it please ?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1**

The macro name is : `Sub calcul(heureOuverture As String, heureFermeture As String)`

If I don't use parameters this is working...

Comment: What macro are you trying to run?

Comment: in the code window, make sure the cursor is in the Sub you want to run first. If it's a function, then you cant run it like that. Was the bas file created with Excel VBA?

Comment: An personal macro called : `Sub calcul(heureOuverture As String, heureFermeture As String)`.

Comment: The only way to run that from the macros dialog is by manually typing in the name of the macro and also the arguments you want to pass. Doesn't really make sense to do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Compile your project. This can be done by Debug > Compile VBA Project

2) Use `Option Explicit` at the top of each module.

3) Before you run the macro use the `Break` (CTRL + Break) and the Rest buttons to ensure clean slate.

4) If you need to pass arguments to a routine you cannot use the Run Sub/Userform (F5) from the VBE as you will need to stipulate the arguments. As such, you can consider something like the below:

```vb
Sub TestCall()

    Call calcul("myStr1","myStr2")

End Sub
```

Comment: Why is compile required? Also, inserting `Option Explicit` may break current code. IMO, only point 4 is related to this question.

Comment: @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ Compile is not required. And you are correct, point 4 is only related to question, but others are there for further understanding as OP seems to not understand some fundamentals in VBA. IMO worth adding to give better context and understanding.

Answer (score 0):

A sub-procedure (Macro) with parameters cannot run directly. It must be called from another macro with required parameter. You may do it like this:

```
Sub CallerMacro()
'calcul "heureOuverture value", "heureFermeture value"
Call calcul("heureOuverture value", "heureFermeture value")
End Sub
```

Comment: That code won't run - you need to remove the brackets.